# Manually adding libraries

Tags: python

Given that every library is a python code itself, I think its logical that instead of using the import command, we can actually copy the whole code of that library and paste it to the top of our main.py.

I'm working on a remote pc, I cannot install libraries, can I use a library by just doing this?

Forgive me if this a very silly question.

Thanks

Comment: *"Given that every library is a python code itself"* - not necessarily true. However, if the library you want to use *is* pure Python; yes, you could just paste the code into your script.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases yes, you can. But there are (a lot of) libraries that have some of their functionality written in C and compiled to binary (e.g. the famous numpy). You can't just paste those.

Another thing that the pasting might introduce are naming colisions. If you use

```
import module
```

than any name in the module `module` can be safely used in the importing module using `module.name` even if the name `name` is already defined somewhere in the importing module. If you just paste the code this won't work.

Answer (score 0):

While pasting the entire library at the top of your main file can work,  I don't think it's the best way to go about solving your problem.

One option is to move the library and put it in to the same folder as your `main.py` file. I believe the import statement will check the current working directory for the library before looking elsewhere.

Another option is to use a virtual environment(`virtualenv`) and then install all the required libraries within this virtual environment. I'm not sure that this will work for you since you said you cannot install on this libraries and `virtualenv` requires `pep`. If you are interested in learning more about python virtual environments, take a look [here](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/).

Answer (score 0):

Most modules are actually written in C, like Pygame for example. Python itself is based on C. You can't jump to conclusions, but if the library is pure Python, I'd suggest copying the package into your project directory and importing, rather than copying and pasting code snippets.